# How do I set a filter that will reject existing records when using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have a Message and Source model related as follows:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sources
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sources, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc{|s| s[:href].blank?}
end

class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :outgoing_message
  validates_presence_of :href
end
```

When I submit my form (built using `form_for` and `fields_for`) it filters out any *new* sources with blank hrefs.  But what I want is for it to delete any existing sources whose hrefs have been set to blank.  Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Does 'existing' mean 'those who were entered before you added this validation' ? In this case, I would simply edit the database (DELETE FROM ... WHERE href IS NULL OR href="").

Answer (score 1):

Hi Inside your `Message` model you may add `validates_associated :sources`
If you need clear all `Message` records with blank `:href` from your database before saving new ones then inside your controller you may write

```
before_filter :some_filter, :only=>[:form_action]
...
def some_filter 
  Source.delete_all("href = '' OR href IS NULL")
end
```